# Wrote TicTacToe in ruby and the computer is not playing nice

Tags: ruby

Basically the computer_make_move method is simple. I just want it to pick an open position and take it. It's meant to be dumb. It's not meant to play skillfully (yet).

Problem is that for some off reason. Every time I make a move, the computer makes a random number of moves.. Sometimes 1, other times 3 or 6. Just strange behavior. I don't understand why.

Note any reference to a method not seen here is in the gameart.rb file and it all art eg. `you_win` is just art, no logic at all.

Here is all the code:

```
class TicTacToe
  require 'colorize'
  require_relative 'lib/gameart.rb'

  attr_reader :home_screen_ninja_art
  WINS = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
  @@scoreboard = {player: 0, computer: 0, tie: 0}

  def initialize name, mark
    @name, @gameover, @game_memory, @winner = name, false, ['_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_'], ''
    mark == 'X' ? (@player, @computer = 'X', 'O') : (@player, @computer = 'O', 'X')
  end

  def menu i
    return render_board if i == 99
    return about if i == 100
    return how_to_play if i == 200
    return scoreboard if i == 300
    return goodbye if i == 400
  end

  def action move
    return menu(move) if move > 10
    current_caller = caller[0] =~ /computer_make_move/ ? @computer : @player
    i = move-1

    if @game_memory[i] == '_'
      render_board(i, current_caller)
    else
      try_again_art
    end
  end

  def computer_make_move
    action(current_board_positions[2].sample+1) # just pick any random open space for now
  end

  def render_board input=nil, caller=nil
    if @gameover == false && !input.nil?
      @game_memory[input] = caller
      verify_game_state
    end
    if @gameover == true
      game_over_art
      case 
      when @winner == 'TIE' then you_tied
      when @winner == @player then you_win
      when @winner != @player then you_lose
      end
    end

    board = @game_memory.map {|ps| ps == 'X' ? ps.colorize(:blue) : ps.colorize(:green) }.map {|ps| ps.gsub(/_/, " ")}
    show_board board
  end

  def current_board_positions
    x_positions, o_positions = [], []
    @game_memory.select.with_index do |v,i| 
      x_positions << i+1 if v == 'X'
      o_positions << i+1 if v == 'O'
    end
    open_positions = (1..9).to_a - (x_positions + o_positions)
    [x_positions, o_positions, open_positions]
  end

  def verify_game_state
    x, o, open = current_board_positions
    find_winner = ->side { WINS.map {|win| side.combination(3).to_a.map {|set| set == win }.include? true } }
    case
    when (find_winner.(x).include? true)
      @gameover=true      
      @winner='X'
    when (find_winner.(o).include? true)
      @gameover=true
      @winner='O'
    when !@game_memory.include?('_')
      @gameover=true
      @winner='TIE'
    else 
      computer_make_move
    end
  end
end
```

This is how I initialize the game:

```
# Start a game 
def start_new_game name, mark
  @f = TicTacToe.new(name, mark)
  puts @f.action 99

  loop do
    if @f.instance_variable_get :@gameover
      puts 'Ready to play again?'.colorize(:white).on_red
      print '   y|yes   '.colorize(:green)
      print '   n|no   '.colorize(:red)
      valid = false
      until valid
        startover = gets.chomp
        valid = true if startover =~ /y|n|yes|no/i  
      end
      if startover =~ /y|yes/i 
        start_new_game name, mark
      else
        @f.goodbye
      end 
    else
      print "*  "
      puts "Make your move #{name}:".colorize(:white).on_red
    end

    move = gets.chomp
    puts @f.action move.to_i
  end
end

valid = false
until valid
TicTacToe.home_screen_ninja_art
puts 'What is your name?'.colorize(:white).on_red
  name = gets.chomp
  valid = true if name.length > 1
end

valid = false
until valid
TicTacToe.home_screen_ninja_art
puts 'Pick your mark?'.colorize(:white).on_red
  print '   X   '.colorize(:blue) 
  print '   O   '.colorize(:green) 
  puts ''
  mark = gets.chomp.upcase
  if mark =~ /X|O/i
    valid = true
  end
end

start_new_game name, mark
```

Comment: `@f.instance_variable_get :@gameover`: 1. You don't have a class to make `@f` a member of, so the `@` should be dropped. 2. Why not just `@f.gameover`, or even better, `@f.gameover?` to follow Ruby conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In method `verify_game_state` that calls after each `render_board` there is no case when person make move. It has only someone winners or tie, OR `computer_make_move`, so no noly computer should make a move.

So every time when it's not the end of the game, computer make a move, until it is, as i can see.

Comment: I think you did narrow it down.. I'm sure it's in that area but I'm not sure I understand what you're saying exactly.

Comment: I think in `verify_game_state` you shouldn't call `computer_make_move` at all. It should just check if it is end of the game. Now it always calls it, until the end of the game.

Comment: Wow I just realized my mistake... I see now what I did. Thanks.